# PHP How to: multiple submit buttons holding different data but the same value

Tags: php, html, forms, post, submit

I have a numeric array (e.g. 0,1,2,3...) displayed in a table. Each row contains an `<input type="submit" name="button" value="Click me">` next to the number to do something with the data from this specific object of the array (which is the number).

Using $_POST I can get the information about the button by its defined name, but they obviously all hold the same value (Click Me) and it wouldn't matter which button you clicked.

To define a new scenario (e.g. with if-functions) for each name of every button is impossible, because I do not now how long the array could be.

Is there a way to use something like an additional ID for the button, which would then be a variable?

Alternatively I could use the array as a name of the input, but then I would need some PHP to do something like:

```php
$x = $_POST[array[]];
if ($x == 0) { do something with array[0];}
```

but for every number of the array.

No matter which number of the array, I always want to do the same thing with it.

Is there either an approach with PHP functions and arrays or in the HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping your array, then you could add a number after the word button that would get higher after every input. Sorry if this is kind of on the rough side, as I'm trying to imagining how your coding may already look.

```
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $a++;
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button$a\" value=\"Click me\">$value";
    }
```

then just loop though the post data

```
    do {
        $x++;
        echo "".$_POST["button$x"]."";

    } while (!empty($_POST["button$x"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Got something similar i'm just using arrays, i also don't know if you can modify your buttons names but i still propose something, first i suppose your code could be something like:

```
$things=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];//.....
?>
<form method="post">
<?php
foreach ($things as $value) 
{
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="button[<?php echo $value?>]" value="Click me"><br>
    <?php
}
?>
</form>
<?php
```

Then after it's send:

```
echo array_search('Click me',$_POST['button']);
```

I think it costs less computing seachring

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. I used href to send the value to next page and $_GET to get the value

```
 <?php
 $numlist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
 for($i=0;$i=count($numlist);$i++)
{
//abc.php being the page you want to sent the data to

echo "<a href='abc.php?value=$numlist[$i]'><button>Click me!</button></a>";
}
?>

<?php
//to get your valueof button clicked inside abc.php

$value=$_GET['value'];
?>
```